# How to increase the font size of a comment in the excel

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm using `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` and worksheet method `write_comment`, to add a comment to a cell.
I want to **increase the font size** of the pushed comment.
It is always taking default size(8).
Is there any way to **increase/set** the size of the font of the comment?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, changing the comment font size in Spreadsheet::WriteExcel isn't possible and there isn't any easy workaround.

Comment: Seeing as John is the author of that module, I would class this as the authoritative answer to this question.

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing in the [documentation for that method](https://metacpan.org/module/Spreadsheet%3a%3aWriteExcel#write_comment-row-column-string-...-) that indicates you can change the format of the comment (other than changing the colour). Which options were you trying to use?

Comment: Successfully: x_scale, color; tried size, font_size, but undone